# generic way to binding JSF uicomponents

Tags: jsf, binding, components

I have the following code of jsf page:

```
 <c:forEach var="componenet" items="#{productsView.productsForm.productAttributes}">
        <ui:component binding="#{componenet}" />
 </c:forEach>
```

All what i want is binding a collection of UIComponenets objects with jsf page. (I use a primefaces). Collections of productAttributes are

```
org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@1f753662
org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@18ef518c
org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@57f98f1b
org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@a74bef6
```

but that dosent work. It is some special tag like

```
<p:componenet binding="#{someUIComponenet}" />
```

or some other way to fix it? I WIll gratefull for help

Comment: here is a long reading if you didnt check yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: i read that. There is informations about jsf binding and how it works. But that informations not resolve these problem.

Comment: That link should have made you to think twice about this approach. It's very likely that it's a completely wrong solution for the actual problem you tried to solve but didn't tell anything about. http://xyproblem.info